# diagnosing "Composer: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" issues

Tags: php, composer-php

I tried updating brianium/paratest from `^6.6` to the latest version of `^7.0` and now, when I try to run `composer install`, I get this message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires vimeo/psalm ^4.29 -> satisfiable by vimeo/psalm[4.29.0, 4.30.0].
    - brianium/paratest[v7.0.0, ..., v7.0.1] require phpunit/phpunit ^10.0.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[10.0.3, 10.0.4].
    - phpunit/phpunit[10.0.3, ..., 10.0.4] require sebastian/diff ^5.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[5.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install sebastian/diff 5.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires brianium/paratest ^7.0 -> satisfiable by brianium/paratest[v7.0.0, v7.0.1].

Error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires vimeo/psalm ^4.29 -> satisfiable by vimeo/psalm[4.29.0, 4.30.0].
    - brianium/paratest[v7.0.0, ..., v7.0.1] require phpunit/phpunit ^10.0.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[10.0.3, 10.0.4].
    - phpunit/phpunit[10.0.3, ..., 10.0.4] require sebastian/diff ^5.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[5.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install sebastian/diff 5.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires brianium/paratest ^7.0 -> satisfiable by brianium/paratest[v7.0.0, v7.0.1].

Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Here's my composer.json:

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "brianium/paratest": "^7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.12",
        "php-parallel-lint/php-parallel-lint": "^1.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.7",
        "vimeo/psalm": "^4.29"
    },
```

I'm not requiring sebastian/diff myself so I can't remove it as a requirement. Per the output I guess phpunit/phpunit is but if it were the only thing requiring sebastian/diff then I don't see how there'd be a conflict. So it seems like something else must be requiring sebastian/diff, albeit a different version, but I have no idea what.

I suppose I could look at each my deps and consider upgrading each one of them, as well, but idk...  that could be a huuuge PITA if I had a lot of deps. Is there no better way to figure out what's going on?

I did do that for my specific composer.json and it looks like PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer (even the latest version of v3.14.3) requires `^4.0` whereas phpunit/phpunit 10.x requires `^5.0` so I guess that's the issue but I feel like I shouldn't need to have to look at each individual repo's composer.json to figure that out.

Comment: When I have this issue I usually go through it one by one. 6.6 -> 7.0 is likely going to have some breaking changes, if theres an opportunity to go to 6.7, 6.8 then 6.9, you might cover some of the issues after each update and then go from there. The other option is to just force it and then do composer update to see if it sorts itself out, but that's hit and miss

Answer (score 5):

Just have a look at the requirements of `vimeo/psalm`. v4 requires `sebastian/diff` in v3 or v4, as you can see on https://packagist.org/packages/vimeo/psalm#4.29.0, and this is obviously incompatible with PHPUnit v10, as this requires `sebastian/diff` in v5.

You could check if your application supports running Psalm v5. And if not, this is a great example for why you should not install tools like Psalm using Composer

---

Also, next time you run such an update, `composer why-not` could help. In your example, `composer why-not brianium/paratest 7.0.1`  could have pointed out the incompatible package

Comment: I did not know about `composer why-not`!